# The Input Process and Output of Facebook Events in different contexts?

Tags: facebook-pages, facebook-groups, facebook-apps, facebook-events

It appears to me that within the realm of Facebook business entities available for posting an event, there are 3 methods in which to post an event:

1. Logged in as a personal account assigned as the admin to a group
2. Logged in as the Facebook Business Timeline Page
3. Logged in as a personal account assigned as the admin to a group [image: Icon of Group Image].

## Methods of Posting an Event 
*(Input)*:

---

### Logged in as a personal account assigned as the admin to a group

[image: Image of creating an event when logged into a personal account that has been assigned as the administrator of a Facebook Group]

> **Note:** This one I understand, everyone in the group will receive an invite to the event.

---

### Logged in as an Admin of your Facebook Timeline Account

[image: Image of being logged in as the admin of]

- The above image displays what happens when posting an event to a FB Timeline Business page when logged into the personal
  account of a person who has been assigned to be the administrator of
  that FB Timeline Business Page.
- Here there is an button to `Select Guests` and clicking it results in a list the friends in the logged in account administrator's personal friend list, which can be checked off to invite.

  - However, these are not the people that I'm looking to notify of the event.  I'd really like to notify all of the people who like the business that the FB Timeline Business page represents.

> **Note:** I have a hunch that maybe this has nothing to do with an administrator account at all, and is just the screen that appears when someone's personal profile tries to display an event on someone's FB Timeline Business Page, but I'm not sure about that.

#### **Why this is confusing:**

Here are the steps I take to reach the screen above:
 1. Inside of my Facebook Timeline Business Page, I click the `Events` App from the `Views and Apps` (or is it `Favorites`?) section of the page.
 2. In the resulting screen you click `Create Event`

---

### Logged in as the Facebook Business Timeline Page

[image: Image of creating an event when logged in as the Facebook Timeline Page]

- The above image is the dialog displayed when attempting to create and
  event when logged in as the Facebook Business Timeline Page.

  - One must first switch their login-type using the `Use Facebook as:` option to do this.

    - [image: Image displaying the Use Facebook as: functionality]

> **Note:** There is no way to `Select Guests` to invite here...does that mean that everyone who likes the Facebook Timeline Business Page will receive an invite?

---

---

## Who gets invited to these events?  *(Process/Output)*?

I know for a fact that when posting an event from a group, all the members of the group receive event invites and the process goes something like this:

1. After an invite is posted from the group by the admin, each user is displayed the invite  as a notification first, [image: Administrator's view of posting the event on the left, and invitiee's notification]
2. If that person accepts the invitation it will eventually display below their ticker feed when the time of the event is nearing.
    [image: user's accepted event invitation reminder displaying below the Facebook ticker feed]

However what I don't know is what happens when you post an event logged in as an admin to a Facebook Timeline Business Page, or when logged in as the Facebook Timeline Business Page itself.

So in summary, my questions are:

- When you are logged in as an admin to a Facebook Timeline Business page and create an event by clicking on the events app, does that event invite all of the users that `like` your Facebook Timeline Business Page?
- When you are logged in as the Facebook Timeline Business page and create an event by clicking on the events app, does that event invite all of the users that `like` your Facebook Timeline Business Page?

Comment: I'm sorry my question is so verbose!  There just seem to be too many ways to do one thing on Facebook!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only send event invitations to friends and group members, not to everyone that likes your page.  However, you can post the event on your page, so that it will appear in the News Feed of people that like your page.  The post will have a Join link for them to RSVP to the event.  If you want more exposure than that there is also the option of purchasing a Facebook ad for the event, in which case numerous targeting options are available (including the ability to target only people that like your page, or friends of those people, or everyone within 50 miles of your city with a certain interest, etc.).